# Using the same image with different IDs in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use the same image repeatedly but with different image ids.  I wanted to know if this is possible as I keep getting the same id repeatedly.

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : urlString,
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(d)
    {


        var numberJSON = d.data.numberOfRows;

        var index = 0;

        for (index = 0; index < numberJSON; index++)
        {

            stockJSON = d[index];

            stockHigh = stockJSON.high;

            stockTicker = stockJSON.stockSymbol;

            // variable definition here and other DOM object stuff ...

            checkMarkDiv = document.createElement('div');

            checkMarkDiv.setAttribute('class', "checkBoxStyleClass");

            nonCheckMarkImage = document.createElement('img');

            nonCheckMarkImageSource = "/images/nonCheckMarkSquare.gif";

            nonCheckMarkImage.setAttribute('src', nonCheckMarkImageSource);

            nonCheckMarkImage.setAttribute('id', stockTicker);

            nonCheckMarkImage.onclick = function() { alert(nonCheckMarkImage.id); };

            checkMarkDiv.appendChild(nonCheckMarkImage);
```

How can I have different ids for the same image represented by `nonCheckMarkImage`?  Is this even possible?  If so, how?  FYI: ticker three to four letter value that is pulled from a JSON object. It's unique on every iteration.

Comment: Do you want multiple IDs on the same image, or do you want multiple copies of the same image with different IDs?  One of these options is impossible....

Comment: Multiple copies of the same image with different IDs.  See this page:  http://www.go-for-me.com/pickachart/test/lows.html

Comment: What does the `id` have to do with `src`. You can use the same `src` with different `id`s. Also, I would use syntax like `checkMarkDiv.className = 'checkBoxStyleClass'`, `nonCheckMarkImage.src = nonCheckMarkImageSource`, `nonCheckMarkImage.id = ticker`. Really, if you can, I would write most of this in HTML, like: `<div class='checkBoxStyleClass' id='whateverTickerIs'>`. Do your JavaScript separate. You might have to assign the `id` with JavaScript.

Comment: I can't see any `jQuery` being used here...

Comment: Are you trying to simply auto-generate `id`s? Your question is unclear.

Comment: @PHPglue I can't do it that way.  The entire page is dynamic so I don't know how many elements will be on the page in advance.

Comment: I want to use the same image repeatedly but with different image ids. I wanted to know if this is possible as I keep getting the same id repeatedly.

Comment: You write dynamic code to deal with it. When you say each ticker is unique with every iteration, I need to see a loop. More code is required for us to determine your problem.

Comment: I just added more code.  Thanks for looking.

Comment: Change `nonCheckMarkImage.setAttribute('id', stockTicker);` to `nonCheckMarkImage.setAttribute('id', stockTicker.toString() + index);` ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but to make it so you need to change the IDs somehow. Is the value of `stockTicker` always the same? This is not a programming question, it's more about sense.

Comment: No you're wrong.  If you look at the code it's a loop.  Each JSON object changes the stockTicker.  I said that in the comments as well.

Comment: @SeanKendle I posted earlier that the stockTicker changes every time.  It iterates automatically.

Comment: What I said will certainly result in different IDs... what confuses me is how you could be looping through different stockJSON.stockSymbol's and getting the same value each time, unless they're all the same value.

Comment: When you check the page source, do you see the images sharing the same ID? Or is it just the alert that's showing always the same?

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Hmmm.... is the alert showing the LAST Id?  Because it looks like you're using the same object over and over, so you're basically setting *all* the images to the same alert box.  Change the alert to `alert(this.id);` and tell me what you get.

Comment: @MelanciaUK All of the ids are actually different so it's working.  But I guess my real question is why onclick am I getting the same ID (the last ID) repeatedly?

Comment: Because you're setting that alert to throw only the last element's ID, as I suspected.  Glad you figured it out!

Comment: You're changing `nonCheckMarkImage` each time, then you ask it to throw `nonCheckMarkImage`'s id.  That's going to be the last element you created.  Try `alert(this.id)` like I said before.

Comment: And, most of this code isn't even jQuery.  Not sure what's up with that.

Comment: @SeanKendle & MelanciaUK Thank you guys.  And PHPGlue you guys helped me figure it out.  I appreciate it.  Thanks again guys.

Comment: I recommend brushing up on jQuery, because after the `$.ajax` line, you've given it up entirely.  The rest of it is just plain javascript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as you said in the comments, the id's are all unique.  You asked in the comments why the alert is showing the same id every time.

It's because in your `onclick` function, you're asking for the object `nonCheckMarkImage`'s id.

That's going to be the last element you created.

Try changing the code within the `onclick` function to: `alert(this.id)`